# Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm working on a project where I am trying to integrate stripe. I'm trying to get payments to go through with one click of the `placeOrderHandler` button. Currently, when I click this button I get an error stating: `Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string`, and then if I click this button again it goes through and `console.log(client_secret)` provides the string associated with it. I'm unsure why this is happening, and I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to fix this. Thank you!

PlaceOrderScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector, createSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {createOrder} from '../actions/orderActions';
import {listProducts} from '../actions/productActions';
import { ORDER_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/orderConstants';
import { PAYMENT_SUCCESS } from '../constants/paymentConstants';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import {CardElement, PaymentElement, CardNumberElement, CardExpiryElement, CardCvcElement, useStripe, useElements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {payment, paymentInfo} from '../actions/paymentActions';
import LoadingSpinner from "../components/LoadingSpinner";


export default function PlaceOrderScreen(props) {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;
  const paymentCreate = useSelector((state) => state.paymentCreate);
  const { client_secret } = paymentCreate;
  const paymentInformation = useSelector((state) => state.paymentInformation);
  const {loadingPayment} = paymentInformation;

  const userId = userInfo._id;
  const orderCreate = useSelector((state) => state.orderCreate);
  const { loading, success, error, order } = orderCreate;
 
  const [loadedPay, setLoadedPay] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { products } = productList;
  useEffect(() =>{
      dispatch(listProducts({}));
    }, [dispatch]);


const elements = useElements();
const stripe = useStripe();
  const placeOrderHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      
       console.log('Stripe.js has not yet loaded.')
        return;
      }
      const paymentMethodType = 'card';
      const currency = 'usd';
      const {error: backendError} = dispatch(payment(paymentMethodType, currency, cart, userId, ));
   
        if (backendError) {
            //addMessage(backendError.message);
            console.log(backendError)
              return;
            }  
  
            console.log('Client secret returned')
            console.log(client_secret)
         
            const {error: stripeError, paymentIntent} = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret,
              {
                payment_method: {
                  card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
                  billing_details: {
                    name: cart.billingAddress.fullName,
                  },
                },
              },
            )
            if (stripeError) {
             
              console.log('stripeError')
              return;
            }
            cart.paymentId = paymentIntent.id
            dispatch(createOrder({ ...cart, orderItems: cart.cartItems }))
            const orderId = order._id;
            setLoadedPay(false)
            .then(dispatch(paymentInfo(orderId)))
            setLoadedPay(true)
          };
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  var loaded = false;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success ) {
       props.history.push(`/order/${order._id}`)
       dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_RESET })  
    }
    
  }, [dispatch, order, success]);




  return (
    <div>
       {loadedPay === false ? (<LoadingBox></LoadingBox>) : (
      <div>
       {loadingPayment & loadingShipping ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : (
    <div>
       {isLoading ? <LoadingSpinner /> : 
    <div>
      <div className="row top">
        <div className="col-2">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div className="card card-body">
                <h2>Payment</h2>
                <div>
      <h1>Card</h1>
      <form id="payment-form" >
        <label htmlFor="card">Card</label>
  {/*<CardElement id="card" />*/}
          <CardNumberElement id="card"/>
          <CardExpiryElement id="card"/>    
          <CardCvcElement id="card"/> 
      </form>
              
            </li>
          
              <li>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={placeOrderHandler} 
                  disabled={isLoading && cart.cartItems.length === 0}
                  className="primary block"
                >
                  Place Order
                </button>
              </li>
              {loading && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
              {error && <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
       }
    </div>
      )}
      </div>
    )}
      </div>
  );
}
```

paymentReducer.js

```
 export const paymentCreateReducer = (state = {client_secret:[]}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case PAYMENT_REQUEST:
        return { ...state, loading: true };
      case PAYMENT_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, loading: false, client_secret: action.payload};
      case PAYMENT_FAIL:
        return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

Backend

stripe.js

```
....

stripeRouter.get(
    '/config',
 expressAsyncHandler((req, res) => {
    res.send({
      publishableKey: '',
    });
  })); 
  
  stripeRouter.post(
      '/pay', 
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
        const userId =  req.body.userId
        const user = await User.findById(userId);
          stripeClient.paymentIntents.create({
                payment_method_types: [req.body.paymentMethodType],
                amount: amount,
                currency: req.body.currency,
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log("There was an error"})
            .then(async function(paymentIntents) {
                
                const clientSecret = paymentIntents.client_secret
                const client_secret = clientSecret.toString()
                res.status(201).send(client_secret)
            })
    }));
```

Comment: could you please provide the code where you're handling the input of the client_secret to the Elements tag?

Comment: @Tarzan Sure, I just added my reducer to the question

Comment: I meant the wrapping component that holds ` <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>`